# django - how to edit this {% for each in members.0 %} to increase members index through a for loop

Tags: django, for-loop

views.py:

```
def main(request):
    ......
    people = ['shargh', 'tehran']
    divvs = [str(i) for i in range(2)]
    members = {}
    n = 0
    for divv in divvs:
        members[divv] = PUserSlidertxt.objects.filter(ostan=os, shahr=sh, senf=senf, username=people[n])
        n = n+1
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'members': members, ....})
```

With `{{ members }}` in main.html file, the output will be:

```
{'0': [<PUserSlidertxt: hi>, <PUserSlidertxt: hello>], '1': [<PUserSlidertxt: goodbye>]}
```

Now I have try this in main.html:

```
{% for each in members.0 %}
    <tr><td style="border:1px solid black; height: 50px;">{{ each.slidertxt }}<br></td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I increase the index of members here to have something like this:

```
{% for each in members.i %}
```

And `i` should be increased.

Comment: You can use `{{ foorloop.counter }}` inside a for loop. It increments on every iteration of the loop. But that might not be what you're looking for. Can you tell us what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The Django template language doesn't have a way to access `members[i]` in the template when `i` is a variable.

You could write a customer template tag. However, in this case, I think it would be better to pass a list of lists to the template, instead of a dictionary.

```
members_list = []
n = 0  # it's not clear why you need n here. Can't you use divv?
for divv in divvs:
    members = PUserSlidertxt.objects.filter(ostan=os, shahr=sh, senf=senf, username=people[n])
    members_list.append(members)
    n = n+1

return render(request, 'main.html', {'members_list': members_list, ....})
```

Then, in the template, you can do a double loop:

```
{% for members in members_list %}
    {% for each in members %}
   <tr><td style="border:1px solid black; height: 50px;">{{ each.slidertxt }}<br></td></tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Any more idea? Any solution?!

Comment: Did you try my answer? Did it work? I'm not sure why you want another idea.

Comment: Yes I did but it did not work. The code I said that is in main.html, is inside a for loop.

Comment: Even if my code does not work exactly, I still recommend that approach. Pass a lists to the template and iterate over them, don't try to increment a counter `i` inside the template.

Comment: Your code will print all indexes from members dictionary directly in one part. I mean everything belongs to user 0 and also to user 1. And as the code is inside an other for loop itself, it will be repeated for many times. I want to the data of user 0 be printed first and after that just the data of user 1. Was it clear?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.